# Grouping and summing a column in response to slicer selections in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table in my model:

| Name | Product | Sale Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Product 1 | 50 |
| Mike | Product 1 | 50 |
| Mike | Product 2 | 50 |
| Adam | Product 1 | 50 |
| Adam | Product 2 | 50 |

I want to create another column in an output table that summarises the 'Sale Value' per 'Name' in another table in response to selections made in a 'Product' slicer.

If 'Product 1' is selected in the slicer, I would like the output in the other table to be:

| Name | Product | Sale Value | Sale Value Summarised |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Product 1 | 50 | 100 |
| Mike | Product 1 | 50 | 100 |
| Adam | Product 1 | 50 | 50 |

I've tried using variations of formulae based on SUMX, CALCULATE, ALL, and ALLEXCEPT but haven't been able to create the desired output table. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say `output` table, are you talking about a visual in power bi or you want this as a table in your data model?  Is `Mike` row intentionally duplicated?  If so, is there an id to distinguish between the two rows?

Answer (score 0):

I think This is what you need! Your expected result is flawed. Please recheck it!

```
Sale Value Summarized = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
                    SUMMARIZE(YourTable,YourTable[Name],YourTable[Product]),
                    "SummaryCol",CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[Sale Value]))
)
RETURN
    SUMX(TblSummary,[SummaryCol])
```

On testing with a table visual:

[image: FERE]